# IOS GLKit : Fading textures dynamically (OpenGL)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, glkit

I am trying to dynamically fade items as they appear further away.

I have this which works fine and textures display fine but does not fade.

```
 effect.texture2d0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
 effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeReplace;
 effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
 effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;

 // transparancy
 glEnable(GL_BLEND);
 glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I then change it to this (based on a few stack overflow posts).  enabling GLKTextureEnvModeModulate or adding glColor4f gives me a error of  GL ERROR: 0x0502

```
effect.texture2d0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeModulate;
effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
effect.texture2d0.name = texture.name;

// transparancy
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); // GL_SRC_ALPHA

glColor4f(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

```
   self.effect.texture2d0.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeModulate;
   self.effect.texture2d0.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
   self.effect.texture2d0.name = mTexture.name;

   self.effect.texture2d1.envMode = GLKTextureEnvModeDecal;
   self.effect.texture2d1.target = GLKTextureTarget2D;
   self.effect.texture2d1.name = mTexture2.name;
```

You will obtain a blending but I still cannot apply a dynamic opacity coefficient.